# Multiples of the plural for spectrum

Tags: grammatical-number

The plural for spectrum is spectra, but when talking about multiple groups of spectra, is it correct to use the word spectras ?

How can multiple groups of spectra be referred to in a single word ?

Comment: The plural of a word doesn't usually change because you have a lot of whatever it is; sould you give an example?

Comment: Multiple bundles of dollars are still *dollars*.

Comment: Multiple spectra is perfectly acceptable.  As is multiple groupings of spectra.

Comment: Double plural is quite tricky. I have multiple groups of books, how should I call them?

Comment: Collective nouns rarely refer to collections of collections. Mathematicians do consider sets of sets, but that is a rare exception.

Comment: @ Łukasz 웃 L ツ In a library, they'd be called sections (a word whose meaning overlaps with the shelving or even room used for those particular books). Or, if they hadn't been put back properly, piles.

Comment: What does it have in its pocketses?

Answer (score 2):

"spectra" is already the plural; saying "groups of spectras" makes no sense, just as you would not say "groups of dogses" when referring to groups comprising subgroups of dogs.

So, you could say "groups and subgroups of spectra"; otherwise, "groups comprising different sets of spectra" or similar.

I myself have not been able to find any authoritative source that uses "spectra" rather than "spectrum" in the singular in the way that Kris describes. [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spectrum), for one, has no singular definition for "spectra", although "a spectrum" can be a collective singular - not for a set of spectra, but for colors that make up a continuum; kinds of organisms; frequency or energy in a continuum; a sequence or range of [eg, interests], etc...

EDIT: I delved further:

Google Scholar has a number (though not a large one) of [hits for "spectras"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22spectras%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=). However, one use is accompanied by the misspelling "antioxydant"; another has "unusual spectras" in a title but "unusual spectra" in the body; and so on. So there is evidence that "spectras" is getting used, but its use is, at least sometimes, in error. I should think that treating "spectra" only as a plural is, for the time being, the safer option.

EDIT 2:

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spectras,spectra,spectrums,%20spectrum&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,spectras;,c0;.t1;,spectra;,c0;.t1;,spectrums;,c0;.t1;,spectrum;,c0) shows a negligible use of "spectras" compared to "spectra". Of course, this doesn't account for "spectra" as singular rather than plural, but "spectras" would certainly be in the plural, and evidence just doesn't stack up that it is (yet) standard usage. "Spectrums" use is also low, but it can be seen in this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spectrums,spectras&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,spectrums;,c0;.t1;,spectras;,c0) that it significantly outweighs that of "spectras" as a plural.

Comment: "unusual spectra" & "unusual spectras" are both correct in technical usage.

Comment: I don't understand. That is exactly what I was trying to find evidence of ("spectras", at least), and have addressed that in my answer.

Comment: See "Usage Note" in my answer.

Comment: With due respect, "agenda" is a different word. Its forms and usage have nothing to do with "spectra" or any other word. We may find that "spectra" eventually goes the way of "agenda" and (sometimes) "data" to be used as a singular, but this is simply not the case now. It may get used as such in technical writing, but so does "spectrum", and it is this which remains the by far more common singular form. I have genuinely tried to find evidence to support, rather than simply refute, your answer, and my findings are quite transparent. I remain interested in being proved wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not common to see **spectra** in writing. When it is, it usually refers to atomic or wavelength spectrums. But yes, you can use *spectra*.

> Three types of [spectrums](http://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/three-types-of-spectrums-spectra/) (spectra) - the curious astronomer
>
> Robert Bunsen and Gustav Kirchoff were a pair of chemists who in 1859 began studying the [spectra](http://astrophys-assist.com/educate/solarobs/ses01p11.htm) of gasses produced by different chemical elements when burned in a laboratory flame. - astrophys-assist.com

I would be prepared to get a little bit of pushback if I used it for much else.

Comment: In the fields of science I am involved in spectra is almost exclusively the plural form of spectrum. Looking over published scientific literature for the period 1998-2014, just over 1000 papers feature the word spectrums as a keyword; compare this with over 409 000 articles where spectra was a keyword. Interestingly, a significant majority of the literature using spectrums comes from countries/territories where English is not the native language.

Comment: @long - thank you for adding that. I find it curious (as an AmE) that there is a relative paucity of *spectra* in English. Is it that less research is coming out of the US?

Comment: US publications: >97K using spectra; 190 using spectrums. Data is from Thomson Reuters Web of Science.

Answer (score 0):

I found some references online to "spectrae" as a way to indicate multiple different types of spectra. It's cute, but possibly niche. I imagine it would be in the same ball park as "peoples" and looks a little more poetic than "spectras."

Comment: Interesting! But of course that just amounts to mistaking "spectra" as a singular (antenna --> antennae) and assigning the wrong ending, rather than pluralising a plural. It would be like saying "sheeps" (or "sheepies" or "sheepen"...).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the context refers to electromagnetic radiation/ quantum mechanics, the term *spectra* is well defined as  "a characteristic" (feature) of a material, under various conditions. [see also: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/High_School_Chemistry/Light_and_the_Atomic_Spectra]

Accustomed to this, scientists tend to speak of a material's "spectra" as "a set of things characterizing" its nature and behavior.

As such, **spectras** has gained usage and acceptance in the context.

[Transactions on Rough Sets VIII](http://books.google.com/books?id=h-UpJg3uD-AC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=define%20%22spectras%22&source=bl&ots=iMprZCVbGv&sig=uAkdKwMvdOMsiceoK9AxP1TqBQ0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0SAUU_CRKbG4iAe7koCQDw&ved=0CGoQ6AEwCA)

> Clearly C* is well defined provided there are no isolated singletons (which is ... If two partial approximation spaces have isomorphic discernibility **spectras**, then ...

*cf*.
 - "[Biodatas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biodatas)"
 - *[a·gen·da](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agenda)*  (ə-jĕn′də) *n*. *pl*. a·gen·das

> ***Usage Note***: It is true that Cicero would have used *agendum* to refer to a single item of business before the Roman Senate, with *agenda* as its plural. But in Modern English a phrase such as *item on the agenda* expresses the sense of *agendum*, and ***agenda* is used as a singular noun** to denote the set or list of such items, as in *The agenda for the meeting has not yet been set*. If a plural of *agenda* is required, the form should be ***agendas***: *The agendas of both meetings are exceptionally varied.* [emphasis added]